# Mapquest Matrix Request URL

Tags: mapquest

I am not sure how to create the request URL if I want to utilize Mapquest Route Matrix

http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/#common

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me.

http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/routematrix?key=KEY&json={locations:[{latLng:{lat:54.0484068,lng:-2.7990345}},{latLng:{lat:53.9593817,lng:-1.0814175}},{latLng:{lat:53.9593817,lng:-1.0514175}},{latLng:{lat:53.9593817,lng:-1.0114175}}],options:{allToAll:%20false}}